# looking at the alphabet ,the letters are numbered 1-26 ,

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, logic

looking at the alphabet ,the letters are numbered 1-26 ,
such that  1 =one=15+14+5=34  (O=15, N=14, E =5 )
           2=two=20+23+15=58 (T=20, W=23, 0=15)
           3=three =56
           4=four=60
           and so on,

can i find a formula such that given any number i can find their sum with regards to their position in the alphabet?

NUMBER   1    2    3     4    5   6   7   8   9    10    11    12

SUM     34   58    56    60   42  52  65  49  42   39    63    87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Look for Lagrange Interpolation polynomial.

You are looking for a function $f$ such that $f(1),..,f(26)$ takes some particular values.

The Lagrange interpolation sais that no matter what those values are, the following polynomial works:

$$f(1) \frac{(x-2)(x-3)...(x-26)}{(1-2)(1-3)...(1-26)}+f(2) \frac{(x-1)(x-3)...(x-26)}{(2-1)(2-3)...(2-26)}+....+f(26) \frac{(x-1)(x-2)...(x-25)}{(26-1)(26-2)...(26-25)}$$

The formula is a polynomial of degree $25$ or lower (most probably 25), so not really nice...

By adding any function of the form $g(x) (x-1)(x-2)...(x-26)$ you get infinitely many other formulas.

Comment: can i further asked on how to work on Lagrange Interpolation polynomial for this sequence? thanks

Comment: @Mark You just plug in $f(1)=34, f(2)=58$ and so on in the above formula. Then multiply everything together, and after extremely long boring messy computations you get your answer....

Comment: @Mark Alternately, write $P(X)=a_{25}X^{25}+...+a_1X+a_0$.  Solving $P(1)=34, P(2)=58...$ leads to a system of $26$ equations with $26$ unknowns, which has unique solution. The solution is exactly the Lagrange interpolation polynomial.

Comment: ok very well appreciated. thank u for alloting time to help me :D